# Git submodules, shared code and XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-submodules

I have a question regarding shared code and XCode using git submodules.

So, I have Consumer app, having it's own repo. I also have a MyLib app, which has its own repo . The MyLib app contains some shared code.

This is what my MyLib looks like:

[image: MyLib XCode structure]

The LibComponents group is what contains all the shared code. The MyLib group contains the AppDelegate and other files for the "demo/example app".

This is what the directory structure looks like:

[image: MyLib dir structure]

Now, I have a Consumer app, in which I wish to use all files from within the "LibComponents" folder. I've added the MyLib as a submodule to my Consumer's git repo.

This is what my consumer app's project looks like:

[image: Consumer Xcode project structure]

Also, this is what my Consumer app's directory structure look like:

[image: Consumer dir structure]

Now, regardless of whether I **update** the files under LibComponent from MyLib or Consumer, and push it to git, it reflects in both places. I'm the owner of both the repositories. This is perfect, as I would like to be able to make minimal changes to the MyLib (shared code) repo when I'm working on my main project (Consumer).

However, I run into a problem with new files. If I add a new file to the MyLib project, push it to git, and pull the changes in my Consumer app, although the local app has the new files, the Consumer app's Xcode project structure does not show the new file. I know that some file in Xcode needs to be told that there is a new file. My question being, what's the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Cheers!

Comment: Try adding the MyLib project to your project instead of just the files. This should update any new files created in your MyLib.xcodeproj

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. If I try to do that, the headers that I require from the LibComponents folder are not accessible from within my project files.

Comment: You will need to adjust your imports I think to remove "MyLib" portion of path if that's what you used to have. I don't know what your imports look like but sub-project headers should be accesible from the main project.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I dragged the MyLib.xcodeproj file into Consumer project, and that did not work. I also dragged the entire folder, and that did not work either (I think that the 2nd method is wrong. Additionally, I tried it and Xcode complained about duplicate method declaration for "main").